# ASP.Net UpdatePanel doesn't do PostBack

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel, postback

I have an ASP.Net page with a long, time-consuming function. I want it to show the "LOADING" word while computing, and show the results when it's done. Here's the code:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel UpdateMode="Always" runat="server" ID="upanel1">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Button ID="btnGetInfo"  runat="server" Text="Lekérés" OnClick="btnGetInfo_Click" />
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
           <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnGetInfo" EventName="Click" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
<asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="upanel1">
    <ProgressTemplate>
        <div>
            LOADING</div>
    </ProgressTemplate>
</asp:UpdateProgress>
```

It's almost working(I can see "LOADING" and after the btnGetInfo_Click function ended, "LOADING" disapperrs). I just need a PostBack when it's done.

I've found some similar problem, but the solutions didn't help me.

Thank You for the answers!

Comment: I am lost you, what you mean you need a PostBack when its done ? When is done the postback all ready have been happens and you get the return. You need a second post back ? and where ?

Comment: Sorry for my bad English. In the btnGetInfo_Click procedure, I set a grid's DataSource. Then I call its DataBind method. After the disappear of the "LOADING" text, the grid does'n show the results. If I want to see the results, I have to do something that causes a postback( for example click on a useless button)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is occurring when you click btnGetInfo is a partial page postback, which refreshes content inside the UpdatePanel ContentTemplate.  The reason your GridView is not updating when you call DataBind() is because it is not inside the UpdatePanel ContentTemplate.

Triggering a full-page postback defeats the purpose of an UpdatePanel.  I recommend that you put your GridView inside the ContentTemplate to fix the problem.